# Cant create a collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm learning node.js with MongoDB. I have installed the complete pack from mongodb.org/downloads.

I made a node.js file look like this:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongo://localhost:27017/myDatabase";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created!");
  db.close();
});
```

In the console it shows me that a database is created, but when I open mongo compass and refresh I don't see any database called *myDatabase*.

So the next thing I tried to is create a collection:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongo://localhost:27017/myDatabase";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;
    db.createCollection("customers", function(err, res) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("Collection created!");
        db.close();
    });
});
```

then I get these errors:

```
Error: Invalid schema, expected `mongodb` or `mongodb+srv`
    at module.exports (D:\Node.js Projects\Node.js MongoDB\node_modules\mongodb\lib\url_parser.js:15:21)
    at connect (D:\Node.js Projects\Node.js MongoDB\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:867:3)
    at connectOp (D:\Node.js Projects\Node.js MongoDB\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:253:3)
    at executeOperation (D:\Node.js Projects\Node.js MongoDB\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:408:22)
    at MongoClient.connect (D:\Node.js Projects\Node.js MongoDB\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:244:10)
    at Function.MongoClient.connect (D:\Node.js Projects\Node.js MongoDB\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:472:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Node.js Projects\Node.js MongoDB\CreateCollection\createcollection.js:4:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
```

Can anyone please help me why I don't see *myDatabase* in MongoDB Compass UI and why I can't create collection when the previous code says that database is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **mongoose** for creating database as well as collection and documentation

here example :-

```
var mongoose = request("mongoose");

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDB', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("database connected");
    }
});
```

You get help from this url
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Answer (score 0):

The connection url should begin with "mongodb://"

---

It seems you're using a newer version of the mongodb library that does not match the tutorial you're following

```
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
var dbName = "myDatabase";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
  if (err) throw err;

  var db = client.db(dbName);
  var collection = db.collection("customers");

  // you are using the collection but it won't be created until you insert a
  // document or create an index

  collection.find({}).toArray((err, docs) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(docs);

    client.close();
  });
});
```

It's better to go to the [official documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/quick-start/quick-start/) that matches your library version

Comment: i changed it to what u said, but still get error: TypeError: db.createCollection is not a function

Comment: The database name in the URL is different in your second snippet "myDatabase" vs "mydb"

Comment: Can you update the question? You're getting a different error now

Comment: i updated my question now.. still getting same error, i tried to change 'mongo' to 'mongodb' and get this error: TypeError: db.createCollection is not a function

Comment: When i refresh my MongoDB Compass UI, i cant see 'myDatabase' that console told me is created ?